# Remainder theorem for polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Trying to help my son out with a homework problem and not sure where I'm going awry.  The question is What must be added to the polynomial 
f(x)= x^5 + x^4 + 3x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 8 
so that the resulting polynomial is exactly divisible by g(x) = x - 2

The remainder theorem says that if f(x) is divided by g(x)=(x-a) then the remainder is f(a), correct?  So in this case, a=2 and we want the remainder to be 0, correct?  Thus we set f(2)+Z = 0 and solve for Z.

That leads me to 2^5 + 2^4 + (3)(2)^3 - (6)(2)^2 - (4)(2) + 8 + Z = 0

Which yields Z = -48.

However, this is a multiple choice question, and the choices are

- -10
- -18
- 10
- 18
- -8

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Crap...missed a term when I was typing it in.  Edited the OP...I had that term in my calculations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved this correctly and none of the answer choices work. (As a check, you can use Wolfram Alpha to check the factorization of polynomials. Type "factor" followed by the polynomial in the search bar.)

Comment: Thanks!  I was beginning to feel very inadequate...